# Run scheduler using cron method in Laravel

Tags: laravel, cron, scheduler

I have an `expires_at` column in one of my models and I want to run a scheduler based on the timestamp of that.

I tried the following code :

```
$collection = Foo::first();
$schedule->call( function() {
    // Do Something
})->cron( \Carbon\Carbon::parse( $collection->expires_at )->format( 'i h d m' ) . ' *' );
```

But when I run `php artisan schedule:run` at the expire date I get `No scheduled commands are ready to run.`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling function you can do that by command. Make command for that cron job and than you can specify that schdeuler in `schedule` method of `kernel.php`

```
schedule->command('command Name')
        ->cron( \Carbon\Carbon::parse( $collection->expires_at )->format( 'i h d m' ) . ' *' );
```

Hope this helps :)